# Derived class container from base class functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, containers

I want to change the type of objects in a container located in a base class based on its derived type. (so the derived class thinks its a container of pointers to type "MyT : T", whereas the base class thinks it is storing pointers to type "T".)

currently i am facing the following scenario. and am simply wondering if there is a better solution.

consider this minimal example

```
class Component
{
public:
    void Update();
};

class MyComponent: public Component
{
public:
    void Update() override {};
    void Draw();
};

class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<Component*> _components; //this container needs to return different types depending on which class is accessing it, so Foo gets a "Componeent*", and MyFoo gets a "MyComponent*.
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _components.size(); i++)
        {
            _components[i]->Update();
        }
    }
};

class MyFoo : public Foo //i guarantee that every pointer in the container in this derived class is of type "MyComponent" rather then "Component"
{
public:
    void Draw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _components.size(); i++)
        {
            ((MyComponent*)_components[i])->Draw(); //how can i remove this cast? (every function in this class makes the same cast)
        }
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyFoo test;
    test.Update(); //should call the basic update
    test.Draw(); //should call the draw of the derived type

    //for clarification consider:
    //test._components <- should be container of type "MyComponent*"
    //((Foo)test)._components <- should be container of type "Component*"
    // note that both examples above are thesame objects, all of actual type "MyComponent" becouse test is of class "MyFoo"
}
```

In this example, i want MyFoo to be able to access the container specified in Foo. However, in the MyFoo class i guarantee that all entrys in the container are of type MyComponent. Hence the cast i make will succeed and work.

However, casting the type for every function i call looks ugly, and is hard to maintain, as there are many functions that need such specific types. furthermore, every seperate function has to cast this entry everytime it is used.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the container located in Foo from type "Component" into type "MyComponent" in the "MyFoo" class, without breaking the functionality that Foo provides.

So that every function in MyFoo can access it like it was a MyComponent*, but the inherited functions from Foo still work as if it was a Component* (except that it calls the overriden function rather then the original).

I am assuming I am missing some pattern, or i should use templates for this.
but i just cant seem to figure this one out.

[Edit] I am not trying to call "Draw" from a pointer to "Component", i am more or less asking for a way to make the container located in "Foo" to change its type depending on the derived class. (in this case, the container of "Foo" has type "Component*" in an instance of "Foo" (as in its declaration). But stores type "MyComponent*"in an instance of "MyFoo" (even though update from "Foo" should still work (the overriden one in this case).

[Edit2] Thesame could be achieved by making a new container of the derived type. but then id have to store every pointer twice, i am wondering if this could be achieved using only 1 vector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to use a derived class function from within a pointer to base class instance the function in base class should be `virtual`. There is [virtual function table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) employed for the purpose. Also, your `Component` class will have to have `Draw` method declared, maybe even as pure `virtual` (i.e. `virtual void Draw() = 0`) if there is no sense for the function to have definition in base class have.

Comment: But then every derived class of "Component" would need to be abstract, or have an implementation of draw. And "Component" itself could not be an instance. I would like component to be an instanceable class, and i would like only methods that make sence for the given class to be visible.

So if i create MyComponent2 : Component with a UpdateState function, that Draw is not visible on this

Comment: While `MyComponent` 'disables' `Update` function I'm not sure that this is ever possible without employing  meta-programming.

Comment: it was not my intention to "hide" the update function. example has been updated. note that it is intended for "Foo" to call the overriden function as expected with normal polymorphism.